# If else condition is not working in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

In reactjs I have created an function in which I have used something like this.

```
const { actions, c } = this.props;
actions.h({
  c: c === 'b' ? 'u' : 'b',
});
```

But in this if codition is not working. What wrong I am doing?

Is there something wrong with actions

The `c` prop is not working.

Also I have used this same function in another component.

It is showing an error :

Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `m_156241`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

I don't know if this warning is happening due to this or not.

Comment: Can you console log c value before the if else statement, and also please share your code on where the warning is.

Comment: @octobus There is no change in console.log

Comment: Can you please show the original code, the current example you are using produces no errors, but, the nature of the original `c` value can be the problem.

Comment: @yfusav can you write some more code about what exactly you are returning in the render.

Comment: Somewhere in your render function's JSX you are using `map` the problem is there with the key you are using. The code you provided has nothing(most likely) to do with the warning.

Comment: @SultanH. In than component, I have used the `c` only in that place.

Comment: @siluverukirankumar In than component, I have used the `c` only in that place.

Comment: @SultanH. Is there something wrong with actions.

Comment: You need to provide more information if you want it to be solved, the reason of the warning is that you are using map function and not giving unique keys to your components in that function, what is the value of the `c` before the if else statement can you console log that and share with us?

Comment: I am also pretty sure that this same question asked in last 2 days.

Comment: @octobus Using console.log it is showing undefined.

Comment: So you can't fetch the c prop. How do you send it? It's likely that you are not sending correctly.

Comment: @octobus I am using that in redux folder.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal This same function is working in another component.

Comment: Yes that's what I am telling you, nothing is wrong with the function, you have problems with map in your JSX of the component which is giving warnings.

Comment: @yfusav what actions.h() will do there, it is a function call, right?